# Scala Unchangeable Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

In Scala 2.10.2, I'd like to be able to create a class of my own which looks like a Map, but allows no modification; i.e. you can look things up in it but you can't modify it.

```
class NoModifyMap extends scala.collection.Map[String,Int] with scala.collection.MapLike[String,Int,scala.collection.Map[String,Int]]
{
    def get( key : String ) = ...

    def iterator = ...
}
```

However, this forces me to also implement `+` and `-` methods, which I don't want. I guess that this is because they're required for `filter`, `map` etc., but is there a sensible way around this problem?

Please note, I'm not asking for an **immutable map**, which can't be changed, but still allows the user to modify a copy of the map - I don't want them to be able to.

I realise that I could do this with a custom map implementation where `+` and `-` throw errors, but that's a nasty code smell.

Comment: Users still would be able to make a manual copy of your map (for example, by calling `Map.apply[A, B](elems: (A, B)*)`) and play with it, so I'm not sure how you want to prevent people from doing that...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "looks like a Map"? If you'd like to pass it in to methods expecting a map there is no way around providing some implementation for all methods of Map. If however you only need it to provide the lookup by key functionality, you could wrap a Map in a custom class that only provides a single method for the lookup.

Comment: Why is it unacceptable for `+` and `-` to be implemented? They don't change the contents of your original data at all. What's the harm if something else copies it? This sounds like an X/Y Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What issue are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: If you upcast a `Map` to `Function1`, users will be able to query the map for specific values but will not have a way to iterate over all of them. This effectively prevents copying.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at  [AbstractMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.AbstractMap). There you shoudn't implement all the methods for map (only `get` and `iterator`).

```
class NoModifyMap extends scala.collection.AbstractMap[String,Int]
{
    def get( key : String ) = ...

    def iterator = ...
}
```

By the way, there's no way to get protection from copying the content of this `Map` into other map, if your `iterator` will return the correct value: the new created Map would just iterate through you map, copying it's values, so the result is the same as for immutable map.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but I get a compile error if I try to inherit from AbstractMap? I can't find the source; it looks like it might be package protected?

Comment: @paulmdavies show the error, please; the class is public, as it appears in the docs

Comment: Inheriting from AbstractMap will not really help here, as you will still have the + and - operators inplemented, you just don't have to implement them yourself.

Comment: @csgero I'm sure these methods in the default implementation of `AbstractMap` would do nothing/throw something like NotSupportedException.

Comment: @ginz maybe I understood the original question wrong, but I think what paulmdavies wants is a something like a Map but without any modifier methods/operators, meaning that it does not have these methods, not that the methods are there but throw exceptions.

Comment: @csgero If he wants to use it as Map, it's impossible in any JVM-based language, just because it won't satisfy condition NoModifyMap IS-A Map

Comment: `AbstractMap` requires you to define the abstract method `+`, so this won't work.

Comment: Hmm, I've missed the point, looking for the methods in the "Abstract Value Members" section.